# JSON from factory not loading

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-service

I am a newbie to AngularJS and have been trying to get JSON from a factory for a few days now. I keep getting the same error which isn't giving me much information:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
```

My module:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
```

Here is my Controller:

```
app.controller('homePageController', function ($scope, projectsFactory) {
    $scope.projects = projectsFactory.getList();
});
```

Here is my Factory:

```
app.factory('projectsFactory', function($http, $q) {
return {
    getList: function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get('Resources/JSON/projects.json').success(function(data){
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }).error(function(){
            deferred.reject();
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    },
};
});
```

Here is the partial page:

```
<ul ng-controller="homePageController">
<li ng-repeat="project in projects">
    {{projects.name}}
</li>
</ul>
```

And here is the JSON itself:

```
[
{
    "Id": 1,
    "name": "Colombo Law",
    "snippet": "Colombo Law snippet"
},
{
    "Id": 2,
    "name": "Lunch?",
    "snippet": "What for lunch snippet"
}
]
```

Here is the complete error message I am getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
at $get (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js:6839:28)
at link (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular-route.js:907:26)
at nodeLinkFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js:6271:13)
at compositeLinkFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js:5682:15)
at publicLinkFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js:5587:30)
at boundTranscludeFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js:5701:21)
at controllersBoundTransclude (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js:6292:18)
at update (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular-route.js:865:25)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$broadcast (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js:12329:28)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular-route.js:556:26 <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Which line is this error on?

Comment: The error is actually just coming from Angular. I added it to the question above...

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of angular don't automatically resolve promises.  Your projects factory is returning a promise and not an actual list, and the ng-repeat won't act on a promise.

I believe what you need to do is assign the result of the promise to your scope variable, like so:

```
app.controller('homePageController', function ($scope, projectsFactory) {
  projectsFactory.getList().then(function(projects) {
    $scope.projects = projects;
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried adding this and am still encountering the same error. I added the error message to the question. Thanks for the response!

Comment: I would suspect something else in your code is causing the actual error.  Are you calling $scope.$broadcast somewhere?  Also you might want to try an unminified version of angular to get a little better idea of where it's blowing up.

Comment: Yea, I have been thinking that as well. I have tried deleting things and seeing if anything changes. If I remove everything from the partial and only have the ng-view="" on the primary page it still errors. I remove the ng-controller and ng-repeat and still and encountering it. I am not referencing $scope.$broadcast anywhere either.